# Symfony subdirectory lib/form/<new_directory>

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am going to program a website in symfony 1.4. It is working very fine. But I have on question.

How can access to a subfolder in lib/forms/

Example:
I have an accountForm.php in

```
/lib/forms/account/accountForm.php
```

How can I get to this in the template and in action, when my module is called "account".

I can include the accountForm.php pretty good, when I am putting it in

```
 /lib/forms/accountForms.php
```

But I want it the other way to have more overview. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but try adding the form's path to autoload.yml
yourProject/config/autoload.yml

use %SF_MODEL_LIB_DIR%/forms if the form is in lib/model/forms

or %SF_LIB_DIR%/forms if the form is in lib/forms

```
autoload:
  customForm:
    name:       yourForm
    path:       %SF_MODEL_LIB_DIR%/forms/accounts/
    recursive:  on
```

Answer (score 6):

Well part of the issues is probably that you havent named the file properly... it should be `AccountForm.class.php` if it is an actual form class. As long as it is named that way it should autoload just fine. Just make sure you clear cache after you have added a new file.

If its not a class then it doesnt belong in a `lib` directory. That exactly is in accountForm.php?

You might also want to customize you autoloading configuration if you are sure of what youre doing: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/14-Other-Configuration-Files

Answer (score 1):

Name the account form `accountForm.class.php` and then in your action you can just do:

`$this->form = new accountForm();`

and in your template:

`echo $form;`